# Update Service Reference file change

Tags: wcf

I am stuck in a very strange problem. I am consuming a wcf service in asp.net project using VS. Everything was fine before, but suddenly wcf service updation started behaving strangly. As soon as i update the service reference by right clicking on the service and selecting Update Service Reference, it deletes all the file and create new file with different name. I got the updated service with different file(wsdl,xsd etc) name because of these I am not able to check in the code.Even delete and add of service reference give the same.

Everytim when I took update service reference, it update the wsdl,xsd file with different name instead of update in the same file.

Looking forward any guidance to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may happen when service name is changed. Could you provide <wsdl:types> section from wsdl file for old and new wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the service endpoint is changing in some way between updates. If the service endpoint changes the service reference will also change accordingly. This is normal and expected.